# Apply function to Cartesian RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to apply a function to cartesian RDDs. The function is taken [from here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and I have no idea how to make it work on cartesian RDDs.

```
val combined = rdd_valid.cartesian(rdd1)
combined.collect().foreach(a  => println(a))

(abcde,abdce)
(somethin,somthing)
(afghr, decsvt)
```

My first thought was to do

```
val newRDD = combined.map(Levenshtein.distance)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `combined` has the type `RDD[(String, String)]`, and `Levenshtein.distance` has this signature:

```
def distance(s1:String, s2:String)
```

You can apply it as follows:

```
val newRDD = combined.map { case (s1, s2) => Levenshtein.distance(s1, s2) }
```

Or, alternatively:

```
val newRDD = combined.map(t => Levenshtein.distance(t._1, t._2))
```

Comment: Yes. That does it. Thank You.What does `case` do in this case?

Comment: It's syntactic sugar (or, shorthand) for `combined.map(t => t match { case (s1, s2) => Levenshtein.distance(s1, s2) }`, which means it's a Pattern Matching expression matching each record in the RDD to a tuple `(s1, s2)`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Any quick way to include the integers in the same RDDs? i.e. `(abcde,abdce, 1)`

Comment: Sure: `combined.map(t => (t._1, t._2, Levenshtein.distance(t._1, t._2)))`